Upgrading SQL SERVER 2014 to 2022 using WIX installer
I am making a exe using Bootstrapper WIX installer for my application. I am trying to update the SQL Server 2014 to SQL Server 2022 using the exe itself.
Here is the scenario, currently the application is installed on the client machine where it locally uses the SQL SERVER 2014. We want to now migrate to SQL SERVER 2022. The upgrade needs to be provided as new version of the application along with some other feature.
I also need to take a backup of the current 2014 SQL SERVER and restore to the 2022 SQL SERVER so that there is no loss of data.This all needs to be done using the exe itself no other client interaction is needed.
Here is what is happening as of now, the older application is creating a SQL SERVER 2014 instance say XYZ, with same name database, now the upgraded SQL SERVER 2022 instance needs to have same name and database (which we will restore).
How can I achieve this what should be the architecture of the application for this problem.
I have been stuck here for past 10 days. Help is highly appreciated.

You're asking several questions, and some of them are quite significant. Upgrading the SQL server is pretty involved. However, it is also a well documented process. I suggest you look into options for unattended installs of SQL server.

If you have any resources please let me know ,

"I also need to take a backup of the current 2014 SQL SERVER and restore to the 2022 SQL SERVER so that there is no loss of data.This all needs to be done using the exe itself no other client interaction is needed." You also should make a full, verified, drive image -- if something goes wrong during upgrade, data alone would not be sufficient to at least get back to the original version!
